# Convert name of day to date format in R

Tags: r, date, character

I want to convert this data in format of date and create new column with the value of month-year:

```
month         : Factor w/ 10 levels "apr","aug","dec",..: 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
day           : chr [1:41188] "mon" "mon" "mon" "mon" ...
year          : num [1:41188] 2008 2008 2008 2008 2008 ...
```

I make a `dput()`

```
dput(head(df))

df <-
structure(list(month = structure(c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), 
.Label = c("apr", "aug", "dec", "jul", "jun", "mar", "may", 
"nov", "oct", "sep"), class = "factor"), day = c("mon", "mon", 
"mon", "mon", "mon", "mon"), year = c(2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
2008, 2008)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

The main of problem is the month and day columns because the format is factor and character

I try the next sentences:

```
as.integer(factor(df$month, levels=month.abb))
```

And this:

```
match(df$month, month.abb)
```

I make it:

```
df$date<-paste(as.character(df$month), df$year)
```

And this worked and returns:

```
$ date          : chr [1:41188] "may 2008" "may 2008" "may 2008" "may 2008"
```

How can I change to date format?

Comment: `with(df, as.Date(paste(year, as.character(month), day)))`?

Comment: In general (and in case my comment does not resolve the issue): (1) *"I get an error"* does not help at all, please include literal text of relevant warnings and errors; (2) your `str` output is somewhat informative but is not data that we can very easily just "use", it is typically better to provide data in a way that we can just copy and paste. In almost every case (and specifically here, due to presence of `factor`s), the gold-standard is to paste the output from `dput(head(df))` into a code-block, as it removes any ambiguity. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I get an error: Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: Thank you for posting the output from `dput`, but you truncated it, please don't do that as the whole thing is important. If you want to subset the columns, then subset them before `dput` and be sure to include the whole output.

Comment: And yes, my first comment is wrong because I missed that `day` is day-of-week and not day-of-month. How can we come up with a date when there are multiple `"mon"` in any particular month?

Comment: It's true, it is not possible. For example, how can I create a column with month and year?

Comment: `df$yearmon <- paste(df$year, as.character(df$month))`?

Comment: There are many `"mon"` in `"may"`. The following code will give you one of them: `lubridate::mdy(apply(df, 1, paste, collapse = "-"))`.

Comment: Or do you want `apply(df[c(2, 1, 3)], 1, paste, collapse = "-")`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas I thought `mdy` presumed day-of-month, not the day-of-week, I'd think this would not find a date.

Comment: @r2evans Right, but it doesn't complain. Package function bug?

Comment: Mis-managed sample data, thanks.

Comment: I'm curious how (more important, why?!?) `lubridate` can arbitrarily choose a day-of-month from day-of-week. (But they're *wrong*, too ... `weekdays(lubridate::mdy(apply(df[c(2, 1, 3)], 1, paste, collapse = "-")))` returns `"Tuesday",...`, when the input is all `"mon"`.)

Comment: @MariaMJ, a very important question is yet unanswered: how do you propose we come up with a single date when all you have is year, month, and day-of-week? Any choice (lacking other context about the source of your data) is arbitrary, do you want the first Monday? Last? Random? While I understand that you are asking for a `Date` object, a `Date` in R includes the day-of-month, and you haven't provided that data or a method for inferring it.

Comment: I have just written the package maintainer, waiting for an answer.

Comment: Thanks for all answers. My first premise was to create a complete date but later I realized that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'll arbitrarily pick the "first" day-of-month for each weekday that you've listed. To make it interesting, I'll change the weekdays so that we have some variability in the data.

```r
df <-
structure(list(month = structure(c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), 
.Label = c("apr", "aug", "dec", "jul", "jun", "mar", "may", 
"nov", "oct", "sep"), class = "factor"), day = c("mon", "tue", 
"wed", "fri", "sat", "sun"), year = c(2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
2008, 2008)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df
#   month day year
# 1   may mon 2008
# 2   may tue 2008
# 3   may wed 2008
# 4   may fri 2008
# 5   may sat 2008
# 6   may sun 2008
```

From here, we need to determine what the 1st day of each month is, and then find the first day-of-week that is at or after that day.

```r
firstdow <- as.POSIXlt(paste(df$year, df$month, "01", sep = "-"), format = "%Y-%b-%d")$wday
# ?strptime says with '%u' that monday is 1
datadow <- match(df$day, c("mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"))
datadom <- (firstdow + datadow - 1) %% 7 + 1
df$date <- as.Date(paste(df$year, df$month, datadom, sep = "-"), format = "%Y-%b-%d")
df
#   month day year       date
# 1   may mon 2008 2008-05-05
# 2   may tue 2008 2008-05-06
# 3   may wed 2008 2008-05-07
# 4   may fri 2008 2008-05-02
# 5   may sat 2008 2008-05-03
# 6   may sun 2008 2008-05-04
```

And proof that this came up with the correct day-of-month to get the first day-of-week:

```r
format(df$date, format = "%a")
# [1] "Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Fri" "Sat" "Sun"
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do 2 things:

1. As `month.abb` is a system constant, we can use it to get numeric `month`
2. Use `as.yearmon` from `zoo` package to get month and year

```
library(zoo)
df %>% 
    mutate(month = match(month, tolower(month.abb))) %>% 
    mutate(new_date = as.yearmon(paste(year, month), "%Y %m"))
```

Output:

```
  month day year new_date
1     5 mon 2008 Mai 2008
2     5 mon 2008 Mai 2008
3     5 mon 2008 Mai 2008
4     5 mon 2008 Mai 2008
5     5 mon 2008 Mai 2008
6     5 mon 2008 Mai 2008
```